# Exception on date::locate_zone with existing timezone

Tags: c++

I've following code:

```
for (const date::time_zone& tz: date::get_tzdb().zones) {
    std::cout << tz.name() << std::endl;
}
std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
auto zone = date::locate_zone("Europe/Berlin");
std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
```

Which is crashing in line 5 (auto zone...)
The output is:

```
...
Europe/Belfast
Europe/Belgrade
Europe/Berlin
Europe/Bratislava
Europe/Brussels
...
Zulu
tzdata.zi
40
12:35:55: Das Programm ist abgestürzt.
```

The 40 is the line in my code.
As I understood by the documentation, locate_zone("Europe/Berlin") should only crash when the time zone isn't existing, but as you can see in the result, it exists.
What I'm doing wrong? Where is my mistake?

EDIT:
Btw, I'm using g++ 11 with C++20 mode.

I also added a try-catch block

```
try {
    auto zone = date::get_tzdb().locate_zone("Europe/Berlin");
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
} catch (const std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

But it isn't arriving the catch block:

```
W-SU
WET
Zulu
tzdata.zi
40
20:33:24: Das Programm ist abgestürzt.
```

Edit 2:
I updated to the newest master branch version (3.0.1) and created an debug version of the library.
In file tz.cpp the error is on line 3592:

```
3585: const time_zone*
3586: #if HAS_STRING_VIEW
3587: tzdb::locate_zone(std::string_view tz_name) const
3588: #else
3589: tzdb::locate_zone(const std::string& tz_name) const
3590: #endif
3591: {
3592:     auto zi = std::lower_bound(zones.begin(), zones.end(), tz_name,
3593: #if HAS_STRING_VIEW
```

The ones with auto zi = ...

Stack trace:

```
1   __memcmp_sse4_1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 memcmp-sse4.S    869  0x7ffff1734b94 
2   std::char_traits<char>::compare                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 char_traits.h    361  0x4c9180       
3   std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>>::compare                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   string_view      314  0x7fffef997311 
4   std::operator<=><char, std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>>, std::__type_identity<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>>>::type)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          string_view      559  0x7fffef99728f 
5   operator()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      tz.cpp           3599 0x7fffef98ce55 
6   __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<date::tzdb::locate_zone(std::string_view) const::<lambda(const date::time_zone&, const string_view&)>>::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const date::time_zone *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, const std::basic_string_view<char>>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<date::time_zone const *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, const std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>> &)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 predefined_ops.h 196  0x7fffef98ecb4 
7   std::__lower_bound<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const date::time_zone *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, std::basic_string_view<char>, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<date::tzdb::locate_zone(std::string_view) const::<lambda(const date::time_zone&, const string_view&)>>>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<date::time_zone const *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<date::time_zone const *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, const std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>> &, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<date::tzdb::locate_zone(std::string_view) const::<lambda(const date::time_zone&, const string_view&)>>) stl_algobase.h   1464 0x7fffef98ed24 
8   std::lower_bound<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const date::time_zone *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, std::basic_string_view<char>, date::tzdb::locate_zone(std::string_view) const::<lambda(const date::time_zone&, const string_view&)>>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<date::time_zone const *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<date::time_zone const *, std::vector<date::time_zone>>, const std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>> &, struct {...})                                                                                                                                                                stl_algo.h       2021 0x7fffef98e786 
9   date::tzdb::locate_zone                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         tz.cpp           3592 0x7fffef98cf92
```

Comment: Are you using the [Time Zone Database Parser](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) extension to get the timezone?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm using. Sorry I didn't mention.

Comment: Is an exception being thrown, and if so, what is the `what()` from the exception?

Comment: I added now a try-catch-block. But the application is just crashing.

Comment: I have no immediate theories as to the cause of the crash.  Do you have a stack trace for the crash?  Does it crash with `-std=c++17`?  Can you reproduce the crash with a minimal example?  How are you building it, with CMake?  Or with a command line direct with the compiler?  Is tz.cpp being built with the same flags as the crashing code?

Comment: Run inside a debugger, you should get some additional information.

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: My best guess at the moment is that the tz.cpp library is being built with different flags than the file with the crashing code.  It could be one of the tz flags such as `USE_OS_TZDB`.  Or it could be the version of c++ (`-std=c++17`).  But in any event, this looks like a build error.  Try just adding tz.cpp directly to your project instead of building it as a separate library.

Comment: Thank you! You gave me a hint! I think it is because a library I'm using is including tz too. And I think it is a different version (IDK which one). 
I'll try to find out how I can use the version of the library. It isn't that easy unfortunately.

Comment: I would've thought the linker would whine about duplicate symbols, but maybe they've been marked weak?  One brute force solution to this is to just rename the `date` namespace in your copy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a C++ Version mismatch. The used library, which includes tz date, is compiled with C++-14. My app is compiled with C++-20. In C++-14 string_view does not exist, causing that error to occur.

When I compile the library with C++-17 or C++-20, it works.

The library itself not being usable is another issue that is not related to this question.